# Syncing .emacs.d folder using personal git server

Tags: git, emacs, openbsd

**Requirements:**

1. Install `git` and `emacs` on OpenBSD 6.1 server (DONE)
2. Put entire `.emacs.d` folder under git version control
3. Clone a "working" repo on server (so that files are visible/usable for server local emacs instance, not just the VC files)
4. Clone `.emacs.d` to all devices

**Actions so far:**

- **On Server:**
- `pkg_add git`
- `pkg_add emacs`
- `mkdir ~/.emacs.d`
- `cd ~/.emacs.d`
- `git --bare init`
- **On Laptop** (with working .emacs.d config)
- `mv ~/.emacs.d .emacs.dbk`
- `rm -rf .emacs.d`
- `git clone test@000.000.000.000:~/.emacs.d`
- copied everything from `.emacs.dbk` to `.emacs.d`
- `git add .`
- `git commit`
- `git push origin master`
- Success
- **Back on Server**
- `ls -a ~/.emacs.d`

  `HEAD         config       hooks        objects      refs
  branches     description  info         packed-refs`

  I'm pretty sure this is good.

**Issues:**

1. I'm not sure how to get a "working" view of my repo. I know the above is the "version control" view (server).
2. I tried to `git clone test@000.000.000.000:~/.emacs.d` on my other devices and I get `SHA 1 errors`

Did I miss a step on the server for folder permissions? 
Anyone else see mistakes?

Thanks

Comment: What exact errpr message do you get? What is your git version?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the bare repo at the server: `git ls-tree HEAD`

Comment: `git ls-tree HEAD` currently yields:

* `100644 blob 22755d4e517f1698c57953a7630fde87bf30fb0c    bbdb`

`100644 blob e0bd203a507bf3809875d3af2368e2cc3300f8fb    bookmarks`

`100644 blob 0ebae31786564c0d36b80a59f5636019e3e20e6f    config.el`

`100644 blob b9328d65e32587dbd990a539872c32e864287170    config.org`

`100644 blob cf54fcb1b889ae27e8378c907b98629917bfcdd7    ido.last`

`100644 blob 37b41e0bbe6488ff60dc0976427e2adc2e3362b9    org-clock-save.el`

Because I pushed my known-good `.emacs.d` folder to it.

Comment: `config.org` = `init.el` in this case. I use a "literate emacs configuration" [per HRS's recommendations](https://harryrschwartz.com/2016/02/15/switching-to-a-literate-emacs-configuration.html).